# Пронумеровать строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с данными необходимо создать отдельный столбец и присвоить каждой строчке уникальный номер от 1 до ...

```
alter table direct_all
add [#Номер] nvarchar(255)

select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Дата]) as [#Номер], Договор, Дата
into #temp_2
from d
```

а вот с апдейтом беда, ведь в изначальной таблице данные не отсортированы, а договор и даты для него могут повторяться MS SQL

Comment: Создайте сиквенцию, и сделайте `update` для каждой записи, получая значение сиквенции. То есть нечто `update TABLE set num=NEXT VALUE FOR YourSequenceName`

Comment: Если нужен НОМЕР, то почему тип - VARCHAR??? сделайте числовой. А если его ещё и автоинкрементным сделать - так он заполнится нужными значениями прямо при создании...

Comment: *договор и даты для него могут повторяться* Вынесите их в отдельную таблицу - и в ней нумеруйте. Заодно и данные нормализуете...

Comment: @Akina судя по предыдущему вопросу нужна группировка по номеру договора. И если идентити уже есть в таблице, второй не сделаешь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам же нужно пронумеровать строки с по номерам договора?
добавьте сначала столбец, затем сделайте cte c нумерацией и проапдейте его

```
with data as (
    select id, [договор]
         , row_number() over (partition by [договор] order by [дата] desc) as rn
    from direct_all
)
update data set [номер] = rn;
```

Если у одного договора может быть несколько одинаковых дат, то надо по другим признакам еще сортировать, если это имеет значение.

Comment: *Если у одного договора может быть несколько одинаковых дат, то надо по другим признакам еще сортировать* Надо не по другим признакам сортирить, а другую функцию использовать. DENCE_RANK().

Comment: @Akina Какой еще `dence_rank` если каждую строку надо различным числом нумеровать? Там человек хотел удалить все кроме последней по дате. было предложено пронумеровать, и удалить где больше 2.

Comment: *Там человек хотел* Я пока лично вообще не понял, что он хочет...

Comment: @teran ругается на скобку последнюю Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @Андрей там в `row_number` косяк, а не в последней. поправил

Comment: @teran Спасибо!